# How to use dependency of dependency in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sequelize.js

Situation: I have a node.js library that uses `sequelize` to define and export models. In my backend app I use this library. This backend app also needs to access to stuff exported by `sequelize`.

Question: What is the correct way of accessing `sequelize` from my backend app?

- I can add sequelize into my backend app's dependencies in package.json, but then if versions don't match some weird things start to happen. This is also hard to maintain, as I have many backend apps and I always have to manually keep track of versions.
- I can access it via `import sequelize from "boxlock-common-server/node_modules/sequelize";`
- ?

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

You can try using package aliases

```
"dependencies": {
   "pkg1": "npm:sequelize@6.23.0",
   "pkg2": "npm:sequelize@6.22.0"
}
```

Comment: How does this help? I don't want to manually keep track of versions in each backend app and the lib

Comment: @ZhaniBaramidze do you know other way to have 2 instances of same package? This helps while it's way to have it. Otherwise you will fall into erros sooner or later that versions not match inside dependency tree with either keeping in sync dependencies of 2 packages or dropping one or another. If you will have another way which would be stable, i can't wait to see it posted in this Q.

Comment: I don't want to have 2 instances, that's the thing :) I want my backend service to automatically use the one from the framework

Comment: if understand right, you have dependency which requires some version & you want to use another version yet also use that dependency. Then you have versions conflict. To resolve that i know 2 ways. 1st - have 2 instances of same package one w/o alias, one with or both. 2nd - resolve versions conflict by dropping one of the dependencies. If you have 3rd option - please post.

Comment: I do not have another version. I want to use the same version in all backend libs. Problem is that I have to 1) manually fix the version exactly in package.json of the framework. 2) manually copy the same version number in all backend libs

Comment: @ZhaniBaramidze sounds like more of question of tooling to keep versions in sync, but it's sounds like out of standard things and something out of npm scope